# React Leaflet Waypoints route in Sea

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

By using **react-leaflet** and **leaflet** npm, I have been implementing ship live location tracker. I have implemented the UI and functionality. But, I need waypoints in sea. But It always showing tracker line on the land. Please refer below codes.

From below code,

JourneyRouteMapView function component used to show the leaflet map

CreateRoutineMachineLayer function component used to show the waypoints and other details.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import RoutingMachine from "./RoutingMachine";

const JourneyRouteMapView = () => {
    const position = [1.2065,103.7709];

   

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-12 h-60 lg:h-full gap-4">
            <div className="col-span-12 opacity-[0.9]">
                <MapContainer center={position} maxZoom={12} style={{width:"100%",height: "100%"}}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        // url='https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
                        // subdomains={['mt1','mt2','mt3']}
                    />
                    <RoutingMachine />
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default JourneyRouteMapView;
```

--*--

```
import L from "leaflet";
import { createControlComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import Ship from "../../../../assets/Icons/ship_route.png";
import "./JourneyRoute.css";

const CreateRoutineMachineLayer = () => {
    let shipIcon = new L.Icon({
        iconUrl: Ship,
        iconSize: [25, 50],
        iconAnchor: [-16, 20],
    });

    var TooltipClass = {
        'className': 'class-tooltip'
      }

    const instance = L.Routing.control({ 
        waypoints: [
            // Previous properly aligned way points
            // L.latLng(1.0703, 104.2192),
            // L.latLng(0.9885398340769811,103.85805624764262),
            // L.latLng(1.0703, 103.7567)
            //New way points
            // L.latLng(1.2230, 103.8542),
            // L.latLng(1.240111, 103.830933),
            // L.latLng(1.2065,103.7709),
            //Sent by mani na
            L.latLng(1.2875422104568421, 103.66667134765369),
            L.latLng(1.247449, 103.596),
            L.latLng(1.2160194097204378, 103.64611489779371),
        ],
        createMarker: function (i, wp, nWps) {
            if (i === 0) {
                return L.circleMarker(wp.latLng,{fillColor: "blue",color: "blue",fillOpacity: 1}).bindTooltip("Journey Starting Point",{permanent: true,direction: "right",...TooltipClass})
            } else if (i === 1) {
                return L.marker(wp.latLng,{icon: shipIcon}).bindTooltip(`7.1 KM`,{permanent: true,direction: "left",...TooltipClass}) //`Current vessel location LatLng : (${wp.latLng.lat},${wp.latLng.lng})`
            } else if (i === 2) {
                return L.circleMarker(wp.latLng,{fillColor: "green",color: "green",fillOpacity: 0.8}).bindTooltip("Journey Ending Point 9.8 KM",{permanent: true,direction: "right",...TooltipClass})
            }
        },
        lineOptions: {
            missingRouteStyles: [{ color: "#6FA1EC", weight: 6 }],
            styles: [{ color: "#6FA1EC", weight: 6 }],
          },
          show: false,
          addWaypoints: false,
          routeWhileDragging: true,
          draggableWaypoints: false,
          fitSelectedRoutes: true,
          showAlternatives: false,
    });
    return instance;
};

const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(CreateRoutineMachineLayer);

export default RoutingMachine;
```

[image]

Comment: I think the lib you are using does not support sea routing only land routing.

Comment: @kboul I think so. If you know any sea route support lib, please share the docs link. That would be really helpful